# Pivot Table Filter (Top Ten)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

how do i filter my pivot table to only show top ten unique results?
i have a column with a count function and when i filter for top 10, sometimes i have over 20 records as most have the same number of count.
this then affects the way my dashboard displays and does not fit properly.

what i am trying to do then is filter my pivot to only show ten results regardless of duplicates.
is this possible?

Comment: In my opinion, Power Query will be a better choice. Please provide a sample about the data source .

Answer (score 0):

When creating your pivot table, select "Add this data to the Data Model":

[image]

If you then use the Top 10 filter in the same way, you will get the results you are after:

[image]